# Getting object not iterable error in django form

Tags: python, django

IN my form i have this

```
 mychoices = User.objects.filter(category__name='city')
```

I get this error

`User Object is not iterable`. I am new to django

This is the next line

```
relevance = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=mychoices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

If i comment this line then i don't see any error

EDIT:

I find the error , i had to use this

```
(choices=[ (o.id, str(o)) for o in User.objects.all()])  Then it works.
```

Does anyone know whats the problem in previous method

Comment: ``objects`` should be iterable, either ``User`` isn't a model, or this isn't where the error is happening. I would bet on the latter, as this error would normally come up in a loop.

Comment: Nonsense it can return an empty list which could result to this error.

Comment: User is a model and i even tried User.objects.all(). it says same error. I am trying all model names and come up with same error.I am trying this in forms.py . is that can be problem

Comment: Please attach the whole traceback.

Comment: I found the problem. See the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify only widget class, not calling constructor:

```
relevance = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=mychoices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**UPDATE**
Choices must be iterable of 2-tuples. First will be value that will be returned in POST request parameters, second - string representation displayed on UI. May be, it makes sense to do something like this:

```
choices = User.objects.filter(category__name='city').values_list('id', 'first_name')
```

You will get:

```
(1, 'Mark')
(2, 'Jack')
...
```

When user selects option and post form, you will receive user ID in parameters, so you will be able to retrieve user object by it.