# Possible to incorporate select tag in django form?

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I have a django form being rendered on an html page, and I have a select dropdown menu which performs a filtering function. I was wondering if it was possible to incorporate this select tag as part of my form? I'd like the select tag to be part of routestep_form.

```
                  <center>        
                  <form class ="subtitle" method = 'POST' action="{% url 'buildpage:partrequestinfo' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                  {{routestep_form.as_p}}

                  <select name = "myselect" id="id_step" onchange="getOptions(this.value)">
                  <option value="-----">-----</option>
                  {% for step in steps %}
                  <option value="{{ step }}">{{ step }}</option>
                  {%  endfor %}
                  </select>
                  <br/><br/>
                  <select id="id_step_option">
                  <option value="-----">-----</option>
                  </select>

                  <input type='submit' value='Next'/>
                  </form>
                  </center>
```

My Form:

```
class RouteStepForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RouteStep
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'step': Select,
            'step_option': Select,
        }

        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(RouteStep)s %(description)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```

Views: The other forms are forms I had on the same page, my main focus though is on RouteStepForm.

```
def partrequestinfo(request):
    steps = Step.objects.all()
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    req_form = PartRequestForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    step_form = StepForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    stepoption_form = StepOptionForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    routestep_form = RouteStepForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if req_form.is_valid() and step_form.is_valid() and stepoption_form.is_valid() and routestep_form.is_valid():
            instance = req_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            step = step_form.save(commit=False)
            step.save()
            stepoption = stepoption_form.save(commit=False)
            stepoption.save()
            routestep = routestep_form.save(commit=False)
            routestep.save()
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else: 
        context = {
                "req_form": req_form,
                "step_form": step_form,
                "stepoption_form": stepoption_form,
                "routestep_form": routestep_form,
                "steps": steps,
        }

    return render(request, "buildpage/partrequestinfo.html", context)
```

Models:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Step Name'), max_length=100, default='')
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.name

class StepOption(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, related_name = 'Step', null = True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Step Option'), max_length=100, default='')
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.name + " - " + self.step.name

class RouteStep(models.Model):
    step_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Step Number'), default = 0)
    step =  models.ForeignKey(Step, related_name = 'Step+', null = True)    
    step_option = models.ForeignKey(StepOption, related_name = 'StepOption', null=True)
    def __unicode__ (self):
            return self.step_option
```

Comment: Where is your form? Did you use django build-in form api?

Comment: Added my form, made the form just using django forms

Comment: Please also add your view.py and model.py

Comment: Done, the other forms are just forms with plain info to be entered in them. My only issue was with creating something like the select tag, or incorporating it into my form.

Comment: Ok, Let's figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
class RouteStepForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['step'].widget.choices=[ query.name for query in Step.objects.all()])
```

If it does not work, please post your template code that show up.

#### EDIT

I edit my answer, and also find this helpful.[Why do I get an object is not iterable error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429084/why-do-i-get-an-object-is-not-iterable-error) and this [Getting object not iterable error in django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911063/getting-object-not-iterable-error-in-django-form).

Another solution will be [Can not iterate a ChoiceField with Select as widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117393/can-not-iterate-a-choicefield-with-select-as-widget)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help so far, got the error: 'Step' object is not iterable